# Different result in same Scala and Java spark functions

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark

I executed simple code written in Java from Spark quickstart guide:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        SparkConf conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Simple Application").setMaster("local[4]");
        JavaSparkContext sc = new JavaSparkContext(conf);
        Accumulator<Integer> counter = sc.accumulator(0);
        List<Integer> data = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
        JavaRDD<Integer> rdd = sc.parallelize(data);
        rdd.foreach(counter::add);
        System.out.println("Counter value " + counter);
}
```

It prints `"Counter value 15"` as expected.
I have code with same logic written in Scala:

```
object Counter extends App {
    val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Simple Application").setMaster("local[4]")
    val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
    val counter = sc.accumulator(0)
    val data = Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
    val rdd = sc.parallelize(data)
    rdd.foreach(x => counter += x)
    println(s"Counter value: $counter")
}
```

But it every time prints incorrect result (<15). What is wrong in my Scala code?

```
Java spark lib "org.apache.spark:spark-core_2.10:1.6.1"
Scala spark lib "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "1.6.1"
```

Comment: can you try using `map` instead of `foreach`? (I know that the result will get discarded, but try it anyway; just call something like `rdd.count()` to force the evaluation)

Comment: @ale64bit I executed `rdd.map(x => counter += x).count()` but it also produces incorrect result

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An advice in the [quick-start](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/quick-start.html#self-contained-applications) documentation says:

> Note that applications should define a main() method instead of
>   extending scala.App. Subclasses of scala.App may not work correctly.

Maybe this is the problem?

Try with:

```
object Counter {
    def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
      val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Simple Application").setMaster("local[4]")
      val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
      val counter = sc.accumulator(0)
      val data = Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
      val rdd = sc.parallelize(data)
      rdd.foreach(x => counter += x)
      println(s"Counter value: $counter")
    }
}
```